# Set heights not changing inline with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code where I am trying to dynamically change the heights of children elements and I am running into something bizarre.  Here is my code so far:

```
var heights = [],
    tallest;
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(elem).children().each(function (i) {
        heights[i] = $(this).height();
        tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
        $(this).height(tallest);
    });
});
```

All this does is find the heights of each child element, pushes it into an array and then finds the biggest value in that array and attempts to set the height based on that value.  One would expect that each child element that is found will change according to what the `tallest` variable value is on resize, but it doesn't -- it stays the same.  However, this code works:

```
var heights = [],
    number = 1000;
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(elem).children().each(function (i) {
        heights[i] = $(this).height();
        tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
         $(this).height(number--);
    });
});
```

The `height` attribute is changed inline with the `number` variable when resizing the window.  What gives?

Why does the second piece of code work and the first one doesn't?  They look like almost the same code to me.

Comment: These divs just have text in them that make the height expand.  Tried giving them a set initial height in CSS...  Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  You have to reset the height every time in the original loop so it pushes a new value into the array.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $(elem).children().each(function (i) {
        $(this).css("height", "");
        heights[i] = $(this).height();
    });
});
```

Solved it for me.

The issue comes when you set the height in the other `each`, it sets the biggest value.  You need to get rid of the inline height each time to retrieve the new value.

Comment: cool.. its weird that you had to reset the height for each child.. but again it works right.. im happy :)

Comment: Haha, yeah totally weird.. Especially when you log `tallest` it gives you the right answer.  Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 1):

It won't assign the max value right away because you're not really calculating the Max height. You have to let it run for all the child elements to get the tallest value. And then run again to assign to each child.

```
 var heights = [],
        tallest;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(elem).children().each(function (i) {
            heights[i] = $(this).height();
        });
        tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
        $(elem).children().each(function (i) {
            $(this).height(tallest);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Furthermore, if only 1 value exists in the `heights` array, that value would be the tallest.  So in my original code example, it would set all of the heights to the shortest one initially and then change to the tallest.

Comment: It would only set the current child(each) to the tallest at the end.. doesn't it?

Comment: Hmmm...  You know what, I think you're right.  I am still having the issue of the inline height not changing though.

Comment: if you're using chrome, try to debug & see if "tallest" is getting a value into it. Logically speaking, my solution should work..I'm calculating the tallest by running through all children & assigning them to all children by running through them again..

Comment: You're logic makes perfect sense, and when I `console.log` the value it does change, just inline on the element it calculates it once and then stops...  Doesn't continue to change.

Comment: Looks like something else is overriding it then.. any other scripts you're running which changes the height again?

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't make any sense that setting a variable like `number` with a value of `1000` works with a decrement operator, but using this does not.

Comment: Figured it out.  Check my answer.